# Unable to send AWS email using my sender id

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services

I am sending AWS email using SNS. It's working fine but the only thing i am unable to find anywhere is how to replace the **no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com** via amazonses.com  id with my own email id..

I had used:

```
$result = $client->publish(array(
    'TopicArn' => $topicArn,
    'Message' => 'testing...',
    'Subject' => 'Test Msg',
    'DisplayName'=>'abc@gmail.com' 
));
```

I have used many other options also but every time it sends email through `no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Did you verify your email on AWS SNS ?

Comment: yes I did it also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can i remove the email id hat comes like no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com.

No, you can't.

> if I have 5 persons subscribed to topic, can All the recipients of the email should be visible to every one.

SNS doesn't consider this as as 1 email sent to 5 recipients.  It sends 5 separate emails, 1 to each recipient.

For these capabilities, you'll need to use Simple Email Service (SES), not SNS.

Comment: Thanks, can you guide me how to send email using SES.. or sample code anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Set attribute `DisplayName` in `setTopicAttributes`.

```
$result = $client->setTopicAttributes(array(
    // TopicArn is required
    'TopicArn' => 'string',
    // AttributeName is required
    'AttributeName' => 'DisplayName',
    'AttributeValue' => 'abc@gmail.com',
));
```

#### Parameters explanation

```
AttributeName => (string)
The name of the attribute you want to set. Only a subset of the topic's attributes are mutable.    
Valid values: Policy | DisplayName | DeliveryPolicy

AttributeValue => (string)
The new value for the attribute.
```

Comment: working fine.. but can i remove the email id hat comes like no-reply@sns.amazonaws.com. Also, if I have 5 persons subscribed to topic, can All the recipients of the email should be visible to every one. @BMW

Comment: Yeah Thanks @BMW. You were a great help

Comment: works pretty well, thnx!